# EF Core ToListAsync throws exception with a Cancellation Token

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am running into an issue that I can't seem to find anywhere. When trying to call `ToListAsync` with a cancellation token, I'll get a null reference exception. But only when the `IQueryable` isn't given a `where` clause. If I have no cancellation token, or pass in `CancellationToken.None`, it works.

PersonService:

```
public class PersonService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    
    public PersonService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPersonsInList(List<int> ids, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var persons = _context.Persons.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable(); 
        //persons = persons.Where(x => x.Id > 0); //adding this line makes things work... I don't know why having no where clauses breaks it.
        if (false)
        {
            persons = persons.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
        }

        var personsResult = await persons.ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

        return personsResult;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Unit test:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task PersonService_GetPersonsInList_ReturnsList()
    {
        //arrange
        Mock<MyDbContext> mockContext = new();
        
        IList<Person> persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new() { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
            new() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
        };
        
        mockContext.SetupGet(x => x.Persons).ReturnsDbSet(persons);
        PersonService personService = new(mockContext.Object);
        
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        
        //act
        var personsResult = await personService.GetPersonsInList(new List<int> { 1, 2 }, cancellationToken);
        
        //assert
        Assert.Equal(persons.Count, personsResult.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never faced with this situation but I guess you don't need this `.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()` ?

Comment: @dcg if I remove the AsEnumerable I'll get:

The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<ClassLibrary1.Person>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: Just some more messing around, replacing the asEnumerable with AsNoTracking seems to be making a difference.  It's just strange.

Comment: That's strange as I've done this multiple times (i.e., `dbContext.Entities.Where(...).ToListAsync(ct)`)...

Comment: Nevermind, it was working with having that where clause added.  I switched it back to false and it's back to getting a null reference exception On the dispose Async

Comment: @dcg But my use case are optional where clauses.  That's why there is the AsQuerable() at the top and all of the where clauses are optional.

Comment: If I add persons = persons.Where(x => x.Id > 0); between the as queryable and the if statement, it works.  But for some reason if there are no where clauses, it throws a null reference exception.

Comment: This has to be something with your mocking. EF Core itself has no issues with such query. `ToListAsync` is EF Core extension method, and it has own requirements for the `IQueryable`, or let say in differently, it can't run on any `IQueryable`. In general mocking db context/sets is not a good idea. Check your mocking library, the object returned by `ReturnsDbSet(persons)` does not implement something EFC expects. Also check the exception stack trace, if the exception is thrown by EFC or something else.

Comment: @ivanstoev I'm going to do a little bit more experimentation on my side but I could have sworn we actually discovered this bug while doing integration tests so it wouldn't have been just a mocking thing. But I will get back to you on that

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few errors with your code:

```
var persons = _context.Persons.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
```

You absolutely do not want the `AsEnumerable()` here. This will materialize the entire table into memory. And the whole point of a cancellation token is to be able to cancel running queries. Instead, use:

```
var persons = _context.Persons.AsQueryable();
```

This is a common thing needed when applying conditional where clauses. It isn't neccesary if you happen to have at least one required `Where` clause you can apply, but if there is no required `Where` clause, either use `AsQueryable()` or:

```
IQueryable<Person> persons = _context.Persons;
```

As you want "persons" to be recognized as an `IQueryable` by default and not a concrete `DbSet<Person>` which will cause issues when you want to reassign based on the conditional `Where`.

```
if (false)
{
    persons = persons.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
}
```

I'm not sure why you'd have `if(false)` other than to test/demonstrate the scenario
where no `Where` clause exhibits the problem.

The reason your scenario fails without an actual `Where` clause is because you have already loaded the entire table into memory, then without anything else to do, trying to run a `ToListAsync()` with a CancellationToken. While you are still ensuring the loaded table (persons) is `IQueryable` it is not an `IQueryable` that is in any state to actually execute anything.

This code should work as expected and ensure that the final `ToListAsync()` is the statement that actually executes the query. I have adjusted the naming slightly to ensure it's clear what the references are actually intended to be:

```
var query = _context.Persons.AsQueryable(); 
if (false) // assuming should be something like if(ids.Any())?
{
    query = query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
}

var persons = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

return persons;
```

I use the term "query" to make it clear that I am building an `IQueryable` and it should remain unexecuted until the last steps where I want the results.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this out a couple minutes here. The whole part about the whole false part was just me being able to test putting a whare statement in there or not. My original code did not have that commented out line so it was just a way for me to have a where clause that I could toggle

Comment: Also, this code was inherited so I wasn't quite sure of the whole as aumerable and as queryable step in there either

Comment: So that "worked" as far as it gives me another error:  The Source Iqueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable.  But that could just be the Mocking library.  I seem to be able to do this against a real database.

Comment: Yes, if you want to mock a method that returns `IQueryable` and use async operations you cannot just return a `List<T>`.  Look for the Nuget package MockQueryable which is a great implementation to enable this. (With Moq)  https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq